# Setting semanticContentAttribute for an instance of UIView does not apply the layout to all of the subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I have a `UIView` instance called parentView, parentView has two subViews:

1- a label called label1

2- anther `UIView` called childView, which has a label called label2.

When calling:

```
self.parentView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

only label1 flips from left to right, Why the childView did not flip, should not the parentView gets flipped with all of it's children?

note: all the view are constrained by leading and trailing constraints.

I know there is one possible solution of iterating over all the child view and set it's `semanticContentAttribute`, is there is any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
func deactivateRTL(of view: UIView) {
    // 1. code here do something with view
    for subview in view.subviews {
        subview.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        deactivateRTL(of: subview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Really helpful, I am using this answer with a twist

Answer (score 1):

The `semanticContentAttribute` property does not propagate to subviews. It is intended to be an isolated use-case and you will have to change the property on each individual view.

If you're having to iterate over children, there is probably a better solution to what you're facing. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have na App in both languages (Arabic-English), and I want to flip a view with all of it's subview, without iterating over all the subviews.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not allowing your customers to use their apps in their iOS system language as they would expect? :)

Comment: There is some Apps that offer language selection as a feature. so user can choose the preferred locale of the App regardless of the device current locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to flip all your views. Hope this will help. Basically you need to apply check of arabic and english and flip it

```
if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "language") as? String == "ar" {
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        } else UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "language") as? String == "en" {
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        }
```

Comment: This wont work for views which should NOT be flipped like logos, images etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shairjeel answer, you can use the following func

```
func switchDirection(view: UIView, newDirection: String) {
    if (newDirection == "ltr") {
        view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    } else {
        view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
    
    for subview in view.subviews {
        switchDirection(view: subview, newDirection: newDirection)
    }
}
```

You can call it like this inside cellForRowAt:

```
switchDirection(view: tableCell, newDirection: "ltr")
```

or for the entire UIView

```
switchDirection(view: view, newDirection: "rtl")
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
```

this will reverse view like a mirror, so you need to do the same to subView

like this:

```
subView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
```

Comment: why (-1)??  if it's wrong please let me know this and the right thing not just given me (-) and gone away

Comment: Because you did not answer the question of the OP, but suggested something else instead, which will make all text in the parent view appear in mirror image.